# Navigation drawer toggle doesn't change state

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I begin a new project, just copy/paste code from an old project where everything is ok. In this one toggle button doesn't change states(it is only arrow and is not working when I am pressing it) like:

[image]

to

[image]

open/close drawer is working fine using swipe touch

Have to notice that I am using only one Activity that have layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/base_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_container_for_fragments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    //elements for screen

</RelativeLayout>


<!--that is just for drawer-->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navigationDrawerList"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="@color/color_red_style" />
```

in my activity:

//declaring vars:

```
private ListView mDrawerList;
protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;
List<DrawerItem> dataList;
```

in `onCreate()` :

```
   dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawerList);

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

`addDrawerItems()` is working ok

```
 protected void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.bar_menu));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("produse");


            // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

and of course I put handle toggle in  `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

```
 // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
```

So what's the problem,I just can't realize... Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this : https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon

Comment: I realised my [fault](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32269830/3595288)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg I forgot to **sync** button toggle state :)

I had to add this in my `MainActivity()` :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```